# 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following error when using Hibernate:

`'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available`

And I am using a datasource for database connection.

Comment: Usually, Hibernate can auto-select the right dialect, but there could be several reasons for this failure. To help understand the problem, some questions: What is the Hibernate version you are using? What is the application server? How are you defining the data source? How does your Hibernate configuration look like? Did Hibernate successfully got the connection?

Comment: Sorry. there was some configuration issue.Now am not getting the above error.

Answer (score 10):

The issue could be that you haven't installed the client library for the database you are trying to connect to.

I have a Spring application that does not have a persistence.xml file and therefore no hibernate.dialect declaration.

Once I installed the [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) client library the error went away.

EDIT: I've also gotten this error when the database server wasn't running.  Something that often happens now that I run my MySQL server through MAMP.

Answer (score 6):

You will get this issue even if you have your configuration files having proper value but you don't configure it in the code.

I was explaining hibernate, I forgot to use `configure()` before `buildSessionFactory()` so I was getting the error.

You might want to recheck it.

**Previous code which was giving me error**

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
```

**Changed code** *No Error*

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 5):

This error is hibernate doing a poor job of telling you what went wrong with your attempted connection with database.

In my case it was as simple as having a wrong password in config file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the property

```
hibernate.dialect
```

In the hibernate (persistence.xml or bean declaration) configuration, the value depends on your database, for example:

```
Postgres: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
Oracle: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

All posible options are listen [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

For example, a sample persistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence-unit>
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: That's not entirely true. You need to set the dialect if you know that Hibernate won't detect it automatically, or if you want to use a custom dialect. But in most of the cases, it should be auto-detected, so, you don't need to set it. This message is usually an indication of something else going wrong .

Answer (score 2):

Just encountered this issue. In my case it was the *hibernate.dialect* configuration.I added the following to SessionFatcory config in spring context file:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.testapp.service.geolocation.LocationData</value>
            <value>com.testapp.service.profiles.Profile</value>
        </list>
    </property>    
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</value>
    </property>
 </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. The reason was missing `<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />` element in `<bean id="sessionFactory">` definition.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases just using a wrong name for the database results in this Exception. Hibernate is apparently trying to determine the dialect before doing anything else, and as the DB cannot be reached, the error message comes from the part responsible for the dialect select. Bad error messaging on part of Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

In the Hibernate configuration dialog has a tab "*options*" it is possible to select some.
In this case I was using **Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse** that already had configured connector, but was still getting the error. Select an option on the list was enough to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same errors. 
My problem was that I put the `hibernate.properties` under one `package` instead of the `src`.
So my solution to my problem was moving `hibernate.properties` from `package` to `src`.